# Android Studio - Create / Open / Import Project Gradle Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, environment-variables

My Android Studio and Gradle was working fine for me a few days ago, i don't know what changed, but now when i am trying to import a project with Gradle, i get the message:

> "You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK
>   components: [Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2]. Before building your
>   project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the
>   installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK
>   Manager. Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license
>   agreements from one workstation to another, go to
>   http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html "

- I use Windows 10
- "java -version" on cmd gives me the java version
- when typing sdkmanager --licences i get:

  > "'sdkmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  >   operable program or batch file."
- Tried to reinstall Andriod Studio, installing newest java version
- The projects i am trying to load are from a Google course in udacity so they should probably work fine (and they did work fine few days ago)
- When I am trying to create a new project with Gradle i get:

  > Failed to create directory "C:\Program Files\Projects\b"
- I did accept the License Agreement during the installation of Android Studio
- My User & System environment variables (photo):
  [User Environment Variables + System Path Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UqGg.png)

Let me know if any other details are needed,
thanks in advance!
Omer

Comment: What is your problem. Why you don't want to accept terms and agreement while installing.

Comment: I did accept the License Agreement. This is why I am surprised

Comment: See my answer below. Notified me if it didn't work.

Comment: Well, clearly sdkmanager isn't on the PATH... Did you try to give the full path to that command?

Comment: what do you mean by "that command"?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to cure this bug. This may occur when you purposely didn't accept the license agreement OR you didn't realize that you didn't accept the license agreement while installing your Android Studio or SDK Build Tools.

In rare cases, bug will occur where you accept the agreement but it didn't record that you did accept it. In that cases you should try below actions:

- Reinstall your Android Studio
- Delete your Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2 in your SDK folder
- Delete your SDK folder and reinstall it from scratch

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you mean:
1. I uninstalled Android Studio
2. I deleted the SDK folder (including Build Tools)
3. I reinstalled Android Studio
Still the same message

Comment: Which part of it?

Comment: accidently pressed enter sorry, i edited my comment. thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Did you reinstall your SDK build tools?

Comment: I deleted all the sdk directory, and it was installed from  scratch when i reinstalled Android Studio. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Do you mind using teamviewer? I need to see your problem more clearly.

Comment: I wish i could told you what the problem is :)
I am using it is my personal computer (i dont know what is team viewer, this is what i understood by googling it).

I deleted the entire sdk folder in
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android

and reinstalled Android Studio.
Is this what you suggested?

Comment: There is too much to ask at the moment considering too many possibilities. I recommended you using teamviewer so that I can see clearly what went wrong here.

Comment: resolved by deleteing everything. appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

Uninstalled, deleted all environment variables, all directories, all caches,
and reinstalled.

Directories that i deleted:

- C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\sdk
- C:\Users\MyUserName\ .android
- C:\Users\MyUserName\ .AndroidStudio2.3
- C:\Users\MyUserName\ .gradle
- C:\Program Files\Android